# Visual Studio 2017 JS Editor weird behaviour when pressing enter

Tags: javascript, interface, visual-studio-2017, editor

I'm currently struggling with Visual Studio 2017 JavaScript editor due to it's following behavior - when I have lines such as

var r = { headers: {} },**|** control = new _hxControl(x);

I put my cursor to where **|** is and press enter to format the var to its own line, VS just cuts off the first character of my variable name and the result is

```
    var r = { headers: {} },
        ontrol = new _hxControl(x);
```

has anybody ran into this issue, too? and found a way to turn off this behavior?

Comment: I have to ask the obvious question.  You've not enabled overwrite instead of insert, have you?  (In the status bar at the bottom of the window it should say **INS** not **OVR**)

Comment: haha no. Also the more trailing spaces there are between cursor and var name prior to pressing Enter, the more characters get removed

Comment: Yeah I did realise that after I posted the comment but it was worth asking anyway.  Do you use any extensions that format code, like Resharper?

Comment: just VS2017 out-of-the-box with that annoying new JavaScript language service disabled

Comment: I've never seen that behavior and just tried it and it doesn't do it for me.  Incidentally, do you really want a pipe before a variable declaration?

Comment: If you mean the | character, that's just an illustration of where I put my cursor

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. This behavior occurs when a Language Service is disabled via Options > Text editor > JS > Language Service

I re-enabled the language service and the issue is gone. The reason behind disabling was that I find the new JS Language Service to be quite annoying, but I guess I'll have to bite it.